# Certain element won't fade in when I scroll past a certain portion of a section

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass, pug

I have a little problem with my code.

As you can see, my example has a three sections. More exactly `landing-page`, `section` and `about`. For the last two I used `CSS grid` to split them each in two subsections.

I'm trying to achieve a `transition` on scroll using `jquery`. Like, when I scroll past a 1/3 of `section`, my `left` element starts to fade from `opacity:0`. Respectively this should happen with my `right` element from my `about` section, but with my code this happens as soon as I scroll past a 1/3 of `section`.

I tried changing the class of my `right.hidden` to `right.hide` and it stopped fading completely.

Bellow I've attached my code and here is a [link](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/vjmWPN) to my CodePen

Jade

```
.landing-page
.section
  .left.hidden
  .right
.about
  .left
  .right.hidden
```

Sass

```
.landing-page
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  background: gray
.section
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  display: grid
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
  grid-template-areas: 'left right' 'left right'
  .left
    grid-area: left
    background: orangered
    transition: 2000ms
  .left.hidden
    opacity: 0
  .right
    grid-area: right
    background: lightblue
.about
  height: 100vh
  width: 100vw
  display: grid
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr)
  grid-template-areas: 'left right' 'left right'
  .left
    grid-area: left
    background: lightgreen
  .right
    grid-area: right
    background: orangered
    transition: 2000ms
  .right.hidden
    opacity: 0
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sectionLeftEl = $('.left'),
      sectionRightEl = $('.right'),
      sectionLeftElOffset = sectionLeftEl.offset().top / 3,
      sectionRightElOffset = sectionRightEl.offset().top / 3,
      documentEl = $(document);

  documentEl.on('scroll', function() {
    if (documentEl.scrollTop() > sectionLeftElOffset && sectionLeftEl.hasClass('hidden')) sectionLeftEl.removeClass('hidden');
    if (documentEl.scrollTop() > sectionRightElOffset && sectionRightEl.hasClass('hidden') sectionRightEl.removeClass('hidden');

  });
});
```

Comment: why changng to hide ? the class is called hidden

Comment: read my post carefully.. i tried changing it because i thought it will fade after I scroll 1/3 past about

Comment: i read the post and still don't see why chaning to a non existing class? you expect what? you have to either remove or add an existing class

Comment: I thought using the class hidden, which is common between the two divs created this transition.
I want my right element to fade after I scroll 1/3 of my about div not after i scroll 1/3 into section. That's why I tried using a different class.

Comment: your issue is with offset calculation, you have TWO right section, and you are gettin the offset of the first one which is the same as the first left one

Comment: increase specificty of your selector `$('.about .right')`

Comment: I still can''t figure this out. I modified my selector as you said and now both of my transitions are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the calculation is wrong (additional of the selectors issue which @Temani Afif mention).

The section offset (right or left) should be

> sectionTopOffset - 2 / 3 * sectionHeight

Just imagine (or test it) that when you start to scroll, you can see the top of `.section`. So you want that whenever you exceed the `.section` in the 1/3 it's like to say `2 / 3 * .section.height()`

So:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sectionLeftEl = $('.section .left'),
    sectionRightEl = $('.about .right'),
    sectionLeftElOffset = sectionLeftEl.offset().top - (2 * sectionLeftEl.height() / 3),
    sectionRightElOffset = sectionRightEl.offset().top - (2 * sectionRightEl.height() / 3),
    documentEl = $(document);

  documentEl.on('scroll', function() {
    if (documentEl.scrollTop() > sectionLeftElOffset && sectionLeftEl.hasClass('hidden')) sectionLeftEl.removeClass('hidden');
    if (documentEl.scrollTop() > sectionRightElOffset && sectionRightEl.hasClass('hidden')) sectionRightEl.removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.landing-page {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: gray;
}

.section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "left right" "left right";
}

.section .left {
  grid-area: left;
  background: orangered;
  transition: 2000ms;
}

.section .left.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

.section .right {
  grid-area: right;
  background: lightblue;
}

.about {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: "left right" "left right";
}

.about .left {
  grid-area: left;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.about .right {
  grid-area: right;
  background: orangered;
  transition: 2000ms;
}

.about .right.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="landing-page"></div>
<div class="section">
  <div class="left hidden"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="about">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right hidden"></div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/moshfeu/pen/jxmYyp?editors=0010